# Eclipse C problems with including .h files

Tags: c, eclipse, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a code. I have the following Structure

```
RLW/RLW.c (inside a folder)
RLW/RLW.h
main.c
```

In the main.c if I have the following line

```
#include "RLW.h"
```

It does **NOT COMPILE** and the line has the error `RLW.h no such file or directory`

if I put the following line in main.c

```
#include "RLW/RLW.h"
```

The  code **COMPILES** but there is still the error `RLW.h no such file or directory`.

I have added the path to the RLW Folder in

Properties->C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes -> GNU C

Any help on how to fix the error?

Comment: Wait, how does the code compile and give errors at the same time? Are we talking about compiler output error or eclipse not being able to find a file?

Comment: give the include as `#include "./RLW/RLW.h"`

Comment: @riodoro1 run time error... may be

Comment: @riodoro1 If I do a `make`from a terminal it compiles. However there is still the sytax error

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu Your solution removed the syntax error. However methods are not correctly imported as, even though it says it finds the file, all methods from RLW are undefined.

Comment: @RicardMolins your question was reagarding inclision of RLW.h file and thats why i solved if it gives further error then ask question in proper way surely we will help

Comment: @VishwajeetVishu you are right, add your comment as an answer and I will select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mentioned that inside folder RLW, RLW.h file is available. `main.c` is present in current working directory(CWD). So to include the folders present in CWD you need to give path as `"./folder/xyz.c"`.Hence giving the include line as `#include "./RLW/RLW.h"` will solve your problem